# Showing that Modus Tollens is sound

Tags: propositional-calculus

When asked to show that Modus Tollens is sound in the propositional calculus, I tried to do this by enumerating all interpretations using a truth table. However I am unsure that my deductions are correct:

$\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
P&Q&P\to Q&\overline{Q}&\overline{P}\\
\hline
T&T&T&F&F\\
F&F&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&T&F\\
F&T&T&F&T
\end{array}$

My understanding is the Modus Tollens is sound, because under the interpretation when $\neg Q$ (rows 1 and 4) and when the implication is true (rows1 and 4), then we can infer $\neg P$. For rows 1 and 2, P is T and F respectively, and the negation here also holds.

I feel that this is insufficient. But I am unsure as to what I am missing.

Comment: @Senex I have further edited your table. Here is [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1848408/revisions) and [link to your revision](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1848408/2). Since you had | in the source but it was not displayed in the post, I guess that this is what you intended to do. But please, check it if you have time. (And if I somehow unintentionally changed what you wanted to get, please, edit the post again.)

Comment: You should refer to row 2 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're missing two, so using your table:

$$\begin{align*}&(P\rightarrow Q)\wedge\neg Q\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;F\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;T\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;F\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;T\end{align*}$$

and finally

$$\begin{align*}&\left[(P\rightarrow Q)\wedge\neg Q\right]\rightarrow\neg P\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;T\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;T\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;T\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;T\end{align*}$$

and we get tautology.

Comment: No, modus tollens doesn't involve a conjunction.  It involves two propositions.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood As you can check wherever you like, it is the same: modus tollens requires that $\;P\rightarrow Q\;$ **and** $\;\neg Q\;$ are true so that $\;\neg P\;$ will be true.

Comment: @AntoineNemesioParras I think is correct, and I've seen this form of Modus Tollens in a couple of textbooks. One other question, with an inference rule, are we trying to infer the value of a proposition or it's Truth? By that I mean, do we care about inferring only Truth or whatever the proposition is, either T or F? --edit, 'sound' means true under every interpretation ... right?

Comment: @user1658296 I've seen it in both equivalent forms, indeed. In this special case we're trying to prove that whenever $\;P\rightarrow Q\;$ and $\;\neg Q\;$ are given, then we can infere $\;\neg P\;$ . As shown above (in the second table) , no matter what the truth values of the atoms $\;P,Q\;$ are, we get a tautology.

Comment: No, it's not the same.  Modus tollens requires that (P -> Q) as well as $\lnot$P hold true.  That means that we have two propositions holding true.  What you wrote in the post consists of a single proposition with $\land$.  $\land$ might not exist in the language, and there might not exist any other symbol for conjunction.  We might have a system with just $\lnot$ and -> *without* any definitions, or work in the definition-free part of the language.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood It is my knowledge that in Prop. calculus all the basic connectives are assumed to exist *unless* otherwise stated. This, and the truth table the poster wrote in his question makes it clear that the connective $\;\wedge\;$ exists. Anyway, even if not we could use connectives equivalence as, for example, the set $\;\{\rightarrow,\,\neg\}\;$ is complete, though I think this is too much for a very elementary question.

Comment: The truth table doesn't mention $\land$.  So, no, it doesn't make it clear that $\land$ exists.  Additionally, NO formal proof (by which I mean a proof where every step is an axiom, a substitution instance of an axiom, or follows from the rules of inference specified) that uses modus tollens as a rule of inference has an inference from a conjunction ((p -> q) $\land$ $\lnot$q) to $\lnot$ p.  They all have an infererence from two formulas one a substitution instance of (p -> q) and another a substitution instance of $\lnot$q.  Consequently, modus tollens doesn't involve a conjunction.

Comment: As you wish, I don't intend to convince you.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood \\ The following is abstracted from the Wikipedia article "modus tollens": Formal notation
The modus tollens rule may be written in sequent notation:

$P\to Q$,$\neg Q\vdash \neg P$
where $\vdash$  is a metalogical symbol meaning that $\neg P$ is a syntactic consequence of $P\to Q$ and $\neg Q$ in some logical system;

or as the statement of a functional tautology or theorem of propositional logic:

$((P\to Q)\land \neg Q)\to \neg P$
where P and Q are propositions expressed in some formal system;

Answer (score 0):

By definition, an inference rule is sound if every expression produced by the rule from a set S of expressions also logically follows from S. Using your truth table, you may show that the expression ¬P logically follows from the set S = {(P→Q),¬Q} by pointing out that every interpretation that satisfies the expressions in S, in this case only row 2, also satisfies the inferred expression ¬P.  Therefore, the inference by modus tollens is sound.